# wkhtmltopdf http error 1301 and 1005

Tags: c#, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to run wkhtmltopdf from my c# code but it keeps returning a 1301 or 1005 error. I can't find anything regarding these error codes, any ideas? I'm using the `--print-media-type` switch so I the pdf will look the same as if it were printed on a physical printer. The pdf does get created, it is just 0 bytes long.

here is the command line parameters:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe http://google.com google.pdf --print-media-type
```

Answer (score 1):

After much heartache and frustration, I've discovered that the `--print-media-type` switch needs to be after the html location BUT BEFORE the pdf location.

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe http://google.com --print-media-type google.pdf
```

works as desired.